# reached while popover is still visible

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

```
-(void)showsearch:(id)sender
{
    SearchViewController *searchview =[[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController" bundle:nil];

    settingpopoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                                    initWithContentViewController:searchview] autorelease];               
    [searchview release];
    [settingpopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender 
                                    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];


}
```

When I click on button, the app is crash and I got `[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.` message.

Comment: you seem to be mixing up *view* and *controller*. is SearchViewController a controller, but you call it a view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

think autorelease is incorrect, here is a tutorial

http://www.jannisnikoy.nl/index.php/2010/04/ipad-tutorial-creating-a-popoverviewcontroller

Comment: @saturngod glad to be of help

Comment: -1 Blog post does not explain why the poster's code crashed. It only is a tutorial for popovers

Comment: @Sanjit Sauja, essentially the addition of `autorelease` in the code IS what makes the code crash. Either you `retain` your `UIPopoverController` or experience the crash that the OP asks about.

Answer (score 6):

There are some good discussions on this topic here:

[Retain/release pattern for UIPopoverController, UIActionSheet, and modal view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867709/retain-release-pattern-for-uipopovercontroller-uiactionsheet-and-modal-view-con)

[UIPopoverController and memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380660/uipopovercontroller-and-memory-management)

The gist of it is you need to:

- assign your autoreleased popover to a retain property
- set the property to nil in your view's dealloc
- as well as setting it to nil in the popoverControllerDidDismissPopover.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is you're setting

```
settingpopoverController =
```

when you mean to do

```
self.settingpopoverController =
```

for which the autorelease would be correct. The second one uses the property accessors, the first just uses the iVar.

Comment: @Sanjit Saluja, in Obj-c 2.0 and beyond, the second syntax -- assuming it's a "retain" property -- would call "retain" on the `UIPopoverController` that the OP calls autorelease on. Otherwise when the current method ends, the `UIPopoverController` is autoreleased, reaches a retain count of 0, and is dealloc'ed. Let me know if you think I'm missing something.