# UIPopOverController inside UISplitViewController

Tags: cocoa-touch, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have to show one popOver inside the left side of one splitController, I initialize the popOver whit an navigationController. But when i show the popOver my app crash.

```
Impostazioni *settings = [[Impostazioni alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
settings.title = NSLocalizedString(@"SETTINGS", nil);
settings.contentSizeForViewInPopover = kContentSizeOfPopOver;
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settings];
nav.navigationBar.tintColor = kTintColorNavigationBar;
nav.contentSizeForViewInPopover = kContentSizeOfPopOver;
UIPopoverController *popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nav];
[popOver presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

This is my code. Any ideas?

EDIT: Crash even if I set only a viewController instead of SplitController :/ And with a empty ViewController :/

Comment: Could you post the crash log, maybe with the NSZombieEnabled http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4

Comment: I've already set NSZombie enabled but no log :/

Comment: You're also leaking memory. You should release all of settings, nav, and popOver.

Comment: I'm working with ARC and solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Possibly duplicate of [Error using UIPopoverController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609122/error-using-uipopovercontroller).)

In short, you need to retain the `UIPopoverController` somehow. Either by defining a property for it or by managing the ref count manually. With ARC, the latter is not an option, so you need to store the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need an instance variable to hold the popoverController. Otherwise after the method that contains the code that you showed finishes nothing will have retained your popover. Unlike when you add a subview to a view which the view would then retain the subview. The same thing does not take place for popovers.