# How is this NOT a Memory Leak

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

I am trying to figure out how the following method does **not** cause a memory leak.  A `UIPopoverController` is allocated, yet, if I include an `autorelease` or `release` call, the application crashes, with the message `'-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.'`.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    [mapView deselectAnnotation:view.annotation animated:TRUE];

    if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) {
        UIViewController *con = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        UIPopoverController *poc = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:con];

        [con release];

        poc.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake( 320, 320 );
        [poc presentPopoverFromRect:view.bounds inView:view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:TRUE];
    }
    else {
        ;   // TODO (miked): display stuff another way
    }
}
```

This seems to go against basic memory management practices.

p.s.  I have not enabled ARC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retain/release pattern for UIPopoverController, UIActionSheet, and modal view controllers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867709/retain-release-pattern-for-uipopovercontroller-uiactionsheet-and-modal-view-co)

Comment: Good question, but I think it's answered by the link above.

Comment: @StilesCrisis You're right, but it did not show up when I was searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This still is a memory leak!

You have to keep a reference to the popover controller in your class and/or implement the delegate method popoverControllerDidDismissPopover: (you can release it there).

A popover controller does not retain itself when you call its "present..."-methods and throws an exception if it is deallocated and still visible

Answer (score 1):

Implemment UIPopoverControllerDelegate's

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController method and do the following.

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {

    if(popoverController == yourPopoverController)

    {

            [popoverController release];

    }

}
```